# handling event in qtruby

Tags: ruby, qt, qt-designer, qtruby

I trying Qt with Ruby and QtDesigner but I don't understand how to handle events. I read and tried signals and slots but I don't see how I customize behavior for example if I want to trigger an action when I click on a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the home page](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Ruby):

```
button = Qt::PushButton.new('Quit') do
  connect(SIGNAL :clicked) { Qt::Application.instance.quit }
end
```